# How to add links in .po (language) file in wordpress?

Tags: plugins, translation

I am beginner in wordpress and I want to know how can I add links in .po file.

Basically I am using Loco Translate to change language text in plugins and theme.

But I need to add Login page link in that text so user should click on link and

after login success user should same.

Comment: ok but how can add links in there?

Answer (score 1):

Don't add links, no need for HTML in there:

How about this:

```
$anchor = esc_html_x( 'Google', 'link text for google.com', 'txt-domain' );
$domain = esc_url( __( 'google.com', 'txt-domain' ) );  
$link   = sprintf( '<a href="https://%s">%s</a>', $domain, $anchor );
```